# Is there a way to know what layout.xml file I'm on while having the app run thru Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I know I can log the names of the xmls, but wondering if there's a more efficient way to easily tell what layout.xml file(s) are being used to render the activity/fragment that is currently visible

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this [Checking app performance](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler)

Its real time approach of system performance, current running activity and Fragment Network uses etc. Go through this doc.